# Decimal numbers not working for the span keyword used in grid layout line placement of grid items

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to achieve a layout like in the image below using CSS Grid Layout:

[The desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfQQA.png)

I've tried to do this myself, but was at this layout below:

[My attempted layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw5LH.png)

The Grid container has the red background, and the items has the green background.

This is my code that I used to try:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="box1">One</div>
            <div class="box2">Two</div>
            <div class="box3">Three</div>
            <div class="box4">Four</div>
        </div>
```

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(3, 3, 41);
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
}

.wrapper div {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    border: 0.2em solid green;
}

.box1 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2 / span 1;
}

.box2 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}

.box3 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    grid-row: 3 / span 1;
}

.box4 {
    grid-column: 3 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2 / span 1;
}
```

I tried using fractional values for the tracks to span `span: 2.5`, but still won't work.

I really want to know if it's possible to achieve such a layout with CSS Grid. Or if you've got a better solution, I'd still appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want 3 rows, you want (I think) 6, then span the div as 2 rows each.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(3, 3, 41);
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 4px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 50px);
}

.wrapper div {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  border: 0.2em solid green;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.box3 {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
}

.box4 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">One</div>
  <div class="box2">Two</div>
  <div class="box3">Three</div>
  <div class="box4">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also discovered that for this particular example, four rows are enough. So I used `grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 50px);` instead. Thanks a lot for the help.